# How to repeat the last yank command N times?

Tags: copy-paste, yank, newlines

I'm just not able able to replicate [the answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/repeat-nth-last-command-in-emacs) on this. Starting with:

```
lipsum
```

I do (my interpretaton):

1. `Alt-W` over the word (copy)
2. Enter (new line)
3. `Ctrl-Y` (paste)
4. `Alt-2 Ctrl-X z` (repeat last two commands)

What I expected:

```
lipsum
lipsum
lipsum
```

What I get:

```
lipsum
lipsumlipsum
```

How did I do wrong?

PS1: breakdown of 1.

- `C-SPC` before `lipsum`
- `C-E`
- `M-W`

Effect: selected region=`lipsum`(cursor at end of line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied only a word, not that word plus the newline character that follows it.

You then yanked the copied word twice. The yanked words aren't separated by newline chars because you didn't include such a char in what you copied to the `kill-ring`.

1. `C-SPC` before the word you want to copy.
2. Then `C-n` to move down a line (to the beginning of the next line).
3. Then `M-w` to copy the word and newline.
4. Then do your yanking (whether by repeating or not).

Comment: "You copied only a word, not that word plus the newline character that follows it." But I repeated the last two commands. The sequence `C-SPC` `C-n` does not move down a line in my case, it selects the word and positions the cursor at the end of the line.

Comment: That's probably because there is no newline at the end of the word. Insert one and then do `C-SPC` at the beginning of the word, then `C-n` to move to after the newline, then `M-w`.

Comment: The problem is `repeat` with an argument does not repeat N times. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Repeating.html and the answer I've added that shows what it actually does.

Comment: @glucas: Good point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to yank something N times, the simplest approach is probably to use a keyboard macro: See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html.

For example, mark and copy the text, then:

1. `F3 C-y F4` ; record a keyboard macro that does the yank
2. `C-u 20 C-x e` ; run last macro 20 times

**Why didn't your approach work?**

Your assumption here is incorrect:

> Alt-2 Ctrl-X z (repeat last two commands)

From the doc for `repeat-command`:

> Repeat most recently executed command. If REPEAT-ARG is non-nil (interactively, with a prefix argument),
> supply a prefix argument to that command.  Otherwise, give the
> command the same prefix argument it was given before, if any.

So `C-x z` will only repeat the last command. In your example you are calling  `yank` with prefix arg 2. Checking what `yank` does with that:

> With argument N, reinsert the Nth most recent kill.

So actually you are yanking the 2nd most recent kill. Try this to see it work. Start with a buffer with this and point at the beginning:

```
one
two
```

Mark and kill one and then two (with trailing newline), e.g.

1. `C-SPC C-n M-w` ; mark, go down a line, copying one
2. `C-SPC C-n M-w` ; same again, copying two
3. `C-y`           ; yank (most recent)
4. `M-2 C-x z`     ; repeat with argument 2 (yank 2nd most recent)

And the end result is this:

```
one
two
two
one
```